# PHP Hash Removal

Tags: php, string

How can I remove all hashes from a string with PHP?

I've tried `str_replace("#","",$message)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: it should work...show us the code

Comment: That should work.  Could you show some more code?

Comment: try `str_replace('#','',$message);`

Comment: probably stripped_message = str_replace('#','',$message);

Comment: @Will Manson don't forget to mark the correct answer :)

Comment: @atno It says I have to wait 3 minutes...

Comment: Which version of PHP is that? On my machine, `echo str_replace("#", "", "### foo ###");` has the same results as `echo str_replace('#', '', "### foo ###");`.

Comment: @zneak PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30) on my machine

Comment: @zneak Apparently PHP Version 5.2.17. Don't worry though, it's fixed now!

Comment: @Will Manson I'm glad for you it works now, but I'm extremely concerned by the solution. It shouldn't have done any significant difference to have the hash symbol inside single or double quotes, so if it really did the trick, you probably uncovered a bug. Do you think you could try to revert back to when it didn't work and show a snippet of code?

Comment: Please provide more details to allow who answers to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) return replaced text.

Example:

```
$a = '### Foo ###';
$a = str_replace('#', '', $a);
echo $a;
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/q39r0J8N)